# *ngFor: meaning of # vs let?

Tags: angular

Am starting out in angular2 and have run into 2 different syntax but am not sure of the difference - or rather how they work.

i see this:

```
 <select class="form-control" required
      [(ngModel)]="model.power"
        ngControl="power" #power="ngForm" >
      <option *ngFor="let p of powers" [value]="p">{{p}}</option>
    </select>
```

but also this works

```
<div *ngFor="#game of games" (click)="gotoGame(game)" class="col-1-4">
        <span>{{game.id}}</span>{{game.name}}
        <br> {{game.description}}
        <br> {{game.genre.name}}
  </div>
```

is one just an alias of the other? what are the advantages of one over the other?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In beta.17 the syntax changed and only this form is valid anymore

```ts
<select class="form-control" required
  [(ngModel)]="model.power"
    ngControl="power" #power="ngForm" >
  <option *ngFor="let p of powers" [value]="p">{{p}}</option>
</select>
```

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta17-2016-04-28

> #### BREAKING CHANGES
>
> The reference `#...` now always means `ref-`.
>
> **Before:**
>
> - Outside of `ngFor`, a `#...` meant a reference.
> - Inside of `ngFor`, it meant a local variable.
>
> This pattern was confusing.
>
> **After:**
>
> - `<template #abc>` now defines a reference to a TemplateRef, instead of an input variable used inside of the template.
> - Inside of structural directives that declare local variables, such as `*ngFor`, usage of `#...` is deprecated. Use `let` instead.
> - `<div *ngFor="#item of items">` now becomes `<div *ngFor="let item of items">`
> - `var-...` is deprecated.
> - use `#` or a `ref-` outside of `*ngFor`
> - for `ngFor`, use the syntax:  `<template ngFor let-... [ngForOf]="...">`

Comment: great, also upgrading ts fixed some wierd behaviour that i had thought was my fault inside ngFor. Double win :D