# ngfor and ngif use localvariable not working

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to create a application with angular 2,i have a accordion menu and want templating the menu...
this is my code :

```
 <ul class="category_vl fold-menu"  >

    <li *ngFor="#wrapper_item_menu of arrayOfKeys">
       <a (click)="menu($event)"    title="" class="clearfix hv2-category-item">
                                <b> {{wrapper_item_menu.name}}  </b>
                                <i>۱۴۲</i>
                                <span class="icon-down-open-big"></span>

                            </a>
                            <ul *ngIf="wrapper_item_menu.items">
                                <li
                                        *ngFor="#submenu of wrapper_item_menu.items"
                                        *ngIf="submenu.name != '_props'"   <============== my error is here!
                                >

                                    <a  [routerLink]="['Inside_group_page', {'name':'asdasd' }]"   >{{submenu.name}}</a>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
```

i want say if submenu.name not equal with '_props' and render the item...
but angular throw an error ...
how to fixed it?
thanks

Comment: Which angular2 version are you using? There are changes in the newest beta release

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36976494/ngfor-meaning-of-vs-let Günter made a clear explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update**

As of 2.0.0 final the canonical form is no longer recommended.

```
  <template ngFor #submenu [ngForOf]="wrapper_item_menu.items">
```

should be

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let submenu of wrapper_item_menu.items">
```

This was introduced because the different syntax of `ngFor let-foo [ngForOf]="bar" and`*ngFor="let foo of bar".

`<ng-container>` behaves the same as the `<template>` but allows to use the more common syntax.

**original**

`*ngIf` and `*ngFor` on the same element are not supported but you can just move the `*ngIf` to the `<a ...`

```
<ul *ngIf="wrapper_item_menu.items">
  <li
      *ngFor="#submenu of wrapper_item_menu.items">
    <a *ngIf="submenu.name != '_props'" [routerLink]="['Inside_group_page', {'name':'asdasd' }]"> 
        {{submenu.name}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In beta.17 the `*ngFor` syntax changed a bit (replace `#` by `let`):

```
<ul *ngIf="wrapper_item_menu.items">
  <li
      *ngFor="let submenu of wrapper_item_menu.items">
    <a *ngIf="submenu.name != '_props'" [routerLink]="['Inside_group_page', {'name':'asdasd' }]"> 
        {{submenu.name}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul *ngIf="wrapper_item_menu.items">
  <template ngFor #submenu [ngForOf]="wrapper_item_menu.items">
    <li *ngIf="submenu.name != '_props'">
      <a  [routerLink]="['Inside_group_page', {'name':'asdasd' }]"> 
          {{submenu.name}}</a>
    </li>
  </template>
</ul>
```

beta.17 syntax

```
<ul *ngIf="wrapper_item_menu.items">
  <template ngFor let-submenu [ngForOf]="wrapper_item_menu.items">
    <li *ngIf="submenu.name != '_props'">
      <a  [routerLink]="['Inside_group_page', {'name':'asdasd' }]"> 
          {{submenu.name}}</a>
    </li>
  </template>
</ul>
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/tQqcw7?p=preview)

Comment: i have a better idea...when submenu.name != '_props' in *ngIf in a tag call a function and remove .closest("li")... :) how to call a function when submenu.name != '_props'  ?!
tnx for comment .

Comment: :D yeaahhh...
i dont want render li...plz say how to call function when equal...tnxx :)

Comment: Them move `ngIf` outside of `<li>` in a `<template>` tag. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the expanded syntax for structural directives (the ones used with the `*` prefix):

```
<template [ngIf]="submenu.name != '_props'">
  <li *ngFor="#submenu of wrapper_item_menu.items">
    (...)
  </li>
</template>
```

This way you would keep the same structure for your HTML...